# Why am I keep getting this query error when I try to create this database?

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I have tried to look online but still, keep running in this problem

```
CREATE TABLE CANDYINVENTORY
(
     CANDY CHAR(40),
     SOLD INT
);

INSERT INTO CANDYINVENTORY (CANDY, SOLD)
VALUES('POLARICE', 1);
```

Failed to execute query.

> Error: There is already an object named 'CANDYINVENTORY' in the database.

Comment: What happens if you try to drop `CANDYINVESTORY` before creating it?

Comment: As the error says, there's already an object with that name.

Comment: By the way, you're trying to create a table and not a database (as your title suggests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run create table query everytime. Just execute insert once the table has been created.

```
INSERT INTO CANDYINVENTORY (CANDY, SOLD) VALUES('POLARICE',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

your table already created in your system now just execute insert query

```
INSERT INTO CANDYINVENTORY
(CANDY, SOLD)
VALUES('POLARICE',1);
```